# Cannot find name in JavaScript file in Angular 4 TypeScript

Tags: angular

I have my own script **extraQU.js** placed in **index.html**.

```
<script src="assets/extraQU/extraQU.js"></script>
```

In **users.component.html** I have:

```
<div [innerHTML]="someVar"></div>
```

In **users.component.ts** I have:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class UserPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }

  someVar = extraQU(
    {
      numbers: [1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0],
      letters: ['T', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'A', 'E'],
    }, 'letters'
  );

}
```

This works fine.

`[innerHTML]="someVar"` displays my function `extraQU`.

```
extraQU.js
```

render in **user.component.html** some `<table> <td> <tr>` etc...

I am satisfied.

But, I don't know why TypeScript highlights in red `extraQU` and show:

```
[ts] Cannot find name "extraQU". any
```

But, I have `extraQU`

```
function extraQU(object, show) {
   ...
}
```

in `<script src="assets/extraQU/extraQU.js"></script>` in **index.html**

In plain JS Website I used:

```
<script>
   var elem = document.getElementById('someVar');

   elem.innerHTML = extraQU(
       {
           numbers: [1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0],
           letters: ['T', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'A', 'E'],
       }, 'letters'
   );
</script>
```

But how to make it work in TypeScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

declare the extraQU variable on the top of the class

> declare var extraQU:any;

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
declare var extraQU:any;
export class UserPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }

  someVar = extraQU(
    {
      numbers: [1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0],
      letters: ['T', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'A', 'E'],
    }, 'letters'
  );

}
```

Comment: Also note that if you have decorators (such as `@Component`) in the file, the declaration must go before those.

Comment: @santoshsingh what is the difference between putting it here vs in typings.d.ts?